# Arduino how do I let people input number from serial monitor and capture the number and assign it to a variable

Tags: arduino

Here is the link so that you guys can edit the code/arduino and try it here : https://www.tinkercad.com/things/kKwzIR4EKkq-project-test/editel?sharecode=_1bgBJa_dekYA2zOBAmrX-fSEpjp10qO9cC2JzeooZg

Basically I want people to input time into the serial monitor and assign it to "long interval" variable. How do I do this?
Arduino image : [Digital Hourglass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPTAS.png)

Arduino code:
(I tried to do but it cant seem to work , It will always just turn on all the lights and when I press the button , the lights will all light up 1 after another as in the interval was 0 so I assume its not assigned yet?)

```
const int switchPin = 8;
unsigned long previousTime = 0;
int switchState = 0;
int prevSwitchState = 0;
int led = 2;
long interval =0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
    delay(2000);  
 
    Serial.println("Input time for alarm in seconds");

 for(int x = 2;x<8;x++){
 pinMode(x, OUTPUT);
 }
 pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
}
void loop(){
 
  if(Serial.available()){

int val = Serial.parseInt(); //read int or parseFloat for ..float...

Serial.println(val);
long interval =val;
   }
 unsigned long currentTime = millis();
 if(currentTime - previousTime > interval) {
 previousTime = currentTime;
digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
 led++;
 if(led == 7){
 }
 }
 switchState = digitalRead(switchPin);
 if(switchState != prevSwitchState){
 for(int x = 2;x<8;x++){
 digitalWrite(x, LOW);
 }
 led = 2;
 previousTime = currentTime;
 }
 prevSwitchState = switchState;
   
}
```

Comment: Inside the `if(Serial.available()){...}` block of code, you are declaring a *brand-new* variable named `interval`, unrelated to the global variable of the same name.  It ceases to exist once you exit that block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Serial.readString()` function to read data from the `Serial monitor` and then pass that data to `atol(const char *)`

`atol` accepts a `const char *` and returns a `long`, so you must convert the `String` to a `char *` by using `String.c_str()`

### Use this Code

```cpp
#define DEFAULT_INTERVAL 1000

const int switchPin = 8;
unsigned long previousTime = 0;
int switchState = 0;
int prevSwitchState = 0;
int led = 2;
long interval =0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    delay(2000);  
 
    Serial.println("Input time for alarm in seconds");

    for(int x = 2;x<8;x++){
        pinMode(x, OUTPUT);
    }
     
    pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

    static long interval = DEFAULT_INTERVAL;
 
    if(Serial.available()){
        String SerialData = Serial.readString();
        interval = atol(SerialData.c_str());

        Serial.println(interval);

    }
    
    unsigned long currentTime = millis();
    if(currentTime - previousTime > interval) {
        previousTime = currentTime;
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        led++;
    
        if(led == 7){
    
        }
    }
    
    switchState = digitalRead(switchPin);
    if(switchState != prevSwitchState) {
        for(int x = 2;x<8;x++)
            digitalWrite(x, LOW);
        
        led = 2;
        previousTime = currentTime;
    }
    
    prevSwitchState = switchState;
   
}
```

**If the input from the `Serial Monitor` is not a number then `atol` will return `0`. You might have to write some code to handle that**

Comment: One thing I want to tell you is that you should seriously work on fomating you code. It will be easier for you and other to read the code